# Horizontal Scalability and disk storage

Tags: virtualization, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to understand how horizontal scalability (virtualization) is working in terms of disk storage.

virtualization is a layer upon the hardware computer nodes and manage the needed resources for the requests.

So my question is what happens when I deploy my war into the web server for example ? I mean I have a replicated storage in different nodes?

After I did some researches I found NAS vs SAN. so i expect to have SAN replication for data stability .... that is true ?

Where is my storage disk exactly when I have a horizontal based server like Google Engine or AWS?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully a couple of these examples will help. Let's take a general, crude  example. I'll try to keep information simple to understand. Let's say I have a business running on LAMP stack. Apache+PHP is running on WEB1 server, MySQL on DB1 server. Customer data sits on WEB1.

### SAN replication

First - your question about replication. That's mostly for disaster recovery. For data stability/reliability, SAN have appropriate RAID levels, service level agreements and spare disks. For example RAID5 tolerates failure of 1 disk in a raid-set. RAID6 tolerates failure of 2 disks in a raid-set etc. Having hot-spare disks help in quick repopulation of failed RAID disk. Organizations also snapshot their disk volumes and replay them in a different data-center so as to have a 2nd copy of their data. This is done over and above regular backups and VM snapshots.

### AWS disks

There are 2 types of disks AWS has:

- Ephemeral: disks connected to EC2 instance
- Elastic Block Storage (EBS)

### Ephemeral storage

Don't use this for anything critical. AWS offers EC2 instances with ephemeral storage (that means, VM has disks attached to the server) and recommends that users purchase slice of their disk in the form of EBS (Elastic Block Storage). I'd chose to not run anything on ephemeral storage because if EC2 instance stops, information on ephemeral storage is gone! However, if my partitions were on EBS volume, EC2 restart will be seamless. All data will stay alive on my EBS volume.

### EBS

When I want a VM, I'd choose an EC2 instance (CPU/Memory). Then I buy disk in the form of EBS volume of 100GB (or more if I want to do RAID/LVM etc.) and attach it to my EC2 instance. Now I can install OS on my EC2 volume. Partitions are all created on my EBS volume. When EC2 reboots, my data stays as-is.

### Disk scaling

Let's say I began my business with an EC2 instance + 100GB of EBS volume. All's well until my customers began to upload really large files. My disk is getting full and I need to expand a partition. With AWS, I could buy another slice of 100GB of EBS volume and expand my partition to use this additional 100GB.

### Server scaling

Let's say my business is doing really well and my EC2 instance isn't keeping up with traffic. I need more horse-power and I choose to add another server WEB2 running Apache+PHP server with its own EBS volume. But what about customer data? Will I store some data on WEB1 and some on WEB2? That'd be hard to reconcile.

### Keeping code same on WEB1 and WEB2

Code from Git (or version control of choice) will be deployed to both WEB1 and WEB2 simultaneously. That will keeps both my server's code up to date. Configuration management of my servers can happen through Ansible/Puppet/Chef.

### Streamlining data storage

I have some options. Let's discuss two options that will allow WEB1 and WEB2 to share data/disk space. Important note - EBS volume cannot be shared with multiple EC2 instances. EBS volume can be attached to only one EC2 instance.

First option - stand up another server DATA1 and attach a large EBS volume to it and move customer files there. WEB1 and WEB2 will send customer data to DATA1 (rsync/ftp/scp). WEB1 and WEB2 will read/write from DB1 database also. I could even safeguard my data by taking snapshots of EBS volume and replaying the snapshot on another server called DATA2 in a different AWS region or availability zone in case DATA1 is unavailable.

Second option - AWS has S3 storage. It's reliable and cheaper than EBS. Instead of standing up DATA1 and DATA2, it is much easier and cheaper to create a bucket on S3 and store customer data there. WEB1 and WEB2 can read/write to S3 seamlessly.

### Where're my disks on AWS?

I don't know, and I don't need to know. AWS must have racks and racks of disks. I am getting a slice of disk space from somewhere there. Their disks are likely to have redundancy but EBS failures are possible. For our own sanity, it is good to RAID and snapshot EBS volumes over and above taking regular backups.

Similar to disks, AWS must have racks and racks of servers. I am getting a virtual machine in the form of EC2 instance of my choice from somewhere in those racks. When I shutdown and restart EC2 server, I may get the same specification VM from a different rack. However, when my EBS volume will remain the same unless I terminate EBS volume and buy a new EBS volume.

One thing to recognize is that if I bought EC2 instance in Oregon, my EBS volume will be in the same Oregon region and also the same availability zone.

Note - this is a very generic answer.